# Grep and print list of strings from two files?

Tags: ruby

I have two large files and I want to take a list of strings (in a third file) and print each string that exists in the first large file but not the other.  I want to run this on the command line as a one liner.

```
#snippet of big_file_1
this is ahello.$ line
blahblah he llo no

#snippet of big_file_2
a 123 line
blahblah help 

# list_of_strings file
hello
address
name

# expected output
=> hello
```

I've tried the following two options.  The first gives me a shell error, the second results in no output.  `hello` is in the first file and not the second so I'm expecting it as output.  Running in IRB, the second option's `if()` returns true. Why am I not getting the `puts` output?

```
ruby -ne 'puts $_ if ((`grep #{$_} big_file_1`.length >0) && !(`grep #{$_} big_file_2`.length >0))' < list_of_strings
ruby -ne 'puts $_ if ((`grep $_ big_file_1`.length >0) && !(`grep $_ big_file_2`.length >0))' < list_of_strings
```

Comment: Any reason it has to be ruby?

Comment: For this specific issue no, but I'm wondering why the Ruby code isn't working.

Comment: Are you looking for lines or for words? And are you matching substrings or whole strings?

Comment: I'm taking the entire line in list_of_strings and am looking for a match anywhere in the line of big_file_1.

Comment: Folks, I'm really trying to figure out why the grep is not working.  If I replace the $_ with a single string it will work (e.g. something is broken with how I'm redirecting input and using $_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first gives me a shell error,

This is because the `-n` ruby option leaves the newline on the `$_`. This also answers your other questions.

To fix this, just `chomp!` it off:

```
ruby -ne '$_.chomp!; puts $_ if ((`grep #{$_} big_file_1`.length >0) && \
  !(`grep #{$_} big_file_2`.length >0))' < list_of_strings
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Comment: This assumes that the entire line is the line in list_of_strings.  I've added inputs and expected output to my example to clarify my question.  Thanks!

Comment: With the revised requirement, add a `select`, `join` and `include?` (though not very efficient)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't have time tonight but feel free to take this and improve it..

Comment: Cary, this should work but I'm wondering why my original grep method does not work (something to do with my use of $_).

Comment: This should do it: `ruby -e 'str1, str2 = File.read("big_file_1"), File.read("big_file_2"); puts File.readlines("list_of_strings").select {|s| str1.include?(s.strip) && !str2.include?(s.strip) }'`.

Comment: @Greg, I did look at your code but I'm not really familiar with using Ruby from the command line.  What I suggested (which you'll see I've changed slightly) is just normal Ruby `eval`'d.  I'll have another look, though.  Maybe @Matt has some insight.

Comment: Bingo, that was the issue.  I tried chomp but I was also chomp-ing the var inside the grep (which didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do in straight bash:

```
cat list_of_strings | while read query
do
  grep -q "$query" big_file_1 && ! grep -q "$query" big_file_2 && echo "$query"
done
```